# How do I fix/create the gprename desktop file in Xenial?

Tags: gprename

I read I should try to use the one from Trusty but it doesn't work:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=2.6
Name=GPRename
Comment=To rename files and directories in batch
Exec=gprename
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/gprename/gprename.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;FileManager;
```

Name[fr_FR]=GPRename

Comment: please what is `gprename` you are talking about

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gprename  -- `gprename` is available in the **universe** repo; add (or enable) then download it with `sudo apt install gprename`  (if you have other problems - you should clarify it beyond "*how do I fix*")

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Xenial `gprename` package currently doesn't provide a `.desktop` file as noted [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gprename/+bug/1573758). It would be helpful if you would [edit] your question to include the contents of yours and explain how you obtained it - and also describe what exactly needs to be fixed.

Comment: You touched the point stelldriver: gprename was yet on my system when I upgraded from Trusty to Xenial. I understand now why uninstalling left the previous desktop file behind.

Comment: I don't know what happened, now it all works. Maybe because I uninstalled/reinstalled or the known issue with apt-xapian-index constantly running. In `/usr/share/applications` I also have two files `gprename-nautilus-actions.xml` and `gprename-nautilus-actions.xml.dpkg-new`.